# class path resource [pointsconfig.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am trying to learn the basic of the Spring framwork. I am using the `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in the sping.xml to print the properties of the PointA but I am getting the error below.

**Triagle class**

```
package org.stack;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class Triangle  {
    private Point PointA;
    private Point PointB;
    private Point PointC;
    private ApplicationContext context = null;

    public Point getPointA() {
        return PointA;
    }

    public void setPointA(Point pointA) {
        PointA = pointA;
    }

    public Point getPointB() {
        return PointB;
    }

    public void setPointB(Point pointB) {
        PointB = pointB;
    }

    public Point getPointC() {
        return PointC;
    }

    public void setPointC(Point pointC) {
        PointC = pointC;
    }

    public void draw() {

        System.out.println("Point A = (" + getPointA().getX() + ", "
                + getPointA().getY() + ")");
        System.out.println("Point B = (" + getPointB().getX() + ", "
                + getPointB().getY() + ")");
        System.out.println("Point C = (" + getPointC().getX() + ", "
                + getPointC().getY() + ")");

    }

}
```

**DrawingApp**

```
package org.stack;


import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        context.registerShutdownHook();
        Triangle triangle =  (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();

    }
}
```

**spring.xml**

```
</bean>

<!-- We intialize here 3 Points objects -->
<bean id="pointA" class="org.stack.Point">
    <property name="x" value="${PointA.pointY}" />
    <property name="y" value="${PointA.pointY}" />
</bean>



<bean id="pointB" class="org.stack.Point">
    <property name="x" value="-20" />
    <property name="y" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="pointC" class="org.stack.Point">
    <property name="x" value="20" />
    <property name="y" value="0" />
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations" value="pointsconfig.properties"></property>
</bean>
```

**pointsconfig.properties file**

```
PointA.pointX=0
PointA.pointY=0
```

[image]

**error**

```
Mai 31, 2016 1:25:24 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMATION: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@619a5dff: startup date [Tue May 31 13:25:24 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Mai 31, 2016 1:25:24 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMATION: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Mai 31, 2016 1:25:25 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFORMATION: Loading properties file from class path resource [pointsconfig.properties]
Mai 31, 2016 1:25:25 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNUNG: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pointsconfig.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pointsconfig.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.stack.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pointsconfig.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:80)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: please add the properties file to classpath during runtime

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Move the `pointsconfig.properties` file to the resources directory.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you try to access to a file in the package `org.stack` so you need to give the full path to `Spring` as next:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:/org/stack/pointsconfig.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: so this is the real root cause of your issue, if you put it in the same package in the source directory it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `pointsconfig.properties` file to the `src` directory. It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:deep/com/sport.properties" />
<bean id ="myTeam" class ="deep.com.CricketTeam">
   <property name="emailAddr" value="${foo.email}"/>
   <property name="teamName" value="${foo.team}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25731864)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

This is how need to use detailed location.